# What causes "mt.exe : genman error Gc1010032: Failed to open scope on file"?

Tags: .net, mt

We run mt.exe on some of our .NET DLLs during our build. We just started getting the following error message:

> mt.exe : genman error Gc1010032: Failed to open scope on file

The command being executed is:

```
mt.exe -managedassemblyname:"path\to\some.dll" -nodependency -nologo -out:"some.dll.manifest"
```

I cannot find any meaningful references either to error code "Gc1010032" nor the term "Failed to open scope on file" at all. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

This extremely confusing error message apparently just meant that the DLL **file was not found**.

This was because of a change made to switch from compiling the DLL from AnyCPU to x86 (for reasons) and Visual Studio changed the default output location from `bin\Release` to `bin\x86\Release`.

I've added this answer just because the error code & message were so obscure.